# Неверный перевод русских букв в unicode на JavaScript

Tags: javascript, unicode

Требуется прочитать текст из файла и перевести его в Unicode. Делаю это посимвольно функцией `charCodeAt`. Проблема в том, что данная функция как будто видит все русские буквы одинаково, то есть `'а'.charCodeAt()` и `'Я'.charCodeAt()` одинаково вернут `65533`.
Пробовал различные функции из интернета типа такой

```
function ord(str){
    var ch = str.charCodeAt(0);
    if (ch>0xFF) ch-=0x350;
    return ch;
}
```

И всегда для разных русских букв на выходе получаются одинаковые значения. Пробовал брать русские символы из текста и вставлять в `console.log();` в итоге в консоле вижу вместо русских букв знаки вопроса "?". Я не очень силён в кодировках, подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно я должен сделать?

Comment: Как вы читаете текст из файла?

Comment: Вы из чего во что хотите перевести его? UТF-8 в UТF-16?

Comment: Вообще говоря, если в javascript у вас есть строка - то **она уже в unicode**! Поэтому вам надо не преобразовывать строку в другую. кодировку - а чинить чтение из файла.

Comment: В Unicode  `U+FFFD`  (65533)  есть � _Replacement Character_ (zаменяющий символ). Тоже знак вопроса `?` есть общий zаменяющий символ для некоторых шрифтов. Надо добавить [mcve]. Кодуровка файла, фрагмент кода читание файла, …